# stretch rows to fill entire height in DataGridView c# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm learning a bit on `DataGridView`

I have a `DataGridView` that I fill with some columns and row from `DataSource`

later I want output a bitmap , for it i want that my columns and rows **fill entire available space**

with columns, I just use (it works fine)

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in DG_dataGridView.Columns)
{
    col.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
}
```

**My problem** that I didn't able to do the same with rows

this my code

```
//columns stretching
foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in DG_dataGridView.Columns)
{
    col.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
}

var printSet = printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings;
DG_dataGridView.Height = printSet.Bounds.Height;

int headerHeight = DG_dataGridView.ColumnHeadersHeight;
int height = DG_dataGridView.Size.Height - headerHeight;
int rowHeight = height / DG_dataGridView.RowCount; // -1;

//rows stretching
for (int i = 0; i < DG_dataGridView.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DG_dataGridView.Rows[i].Height = rowHeight;
}

Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(DG_dataGridView.Width, DG_dataGridView.Height);

DG_dataGridView.DrawToBitmap(bm, new Rectangle(0, 0, DG_dataGridView.Width, DG_dataGridView.Height));

bm.Save(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\latestBitTable.bmp");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this might be caused by the `AutoSizeRowsMode` property. When it is set to `AllCells` for example, the rows will be automatically re-sized to fit the cell contents (regardless of how you defined or set it in code).

Perhaps setting it to `None` might solve your problem.

```
dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.None;
```

The following documentation might be of use to you when programming your wanted behavior: [Sizing Options in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b2wakt.aspx)